# How to send an image together with form data using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests python to create a post request together with the submit form data.
Here it is the HTML form:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload">
            <span class="filename"></span>
            <input type="file" class="input" name="image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="upload-btn" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here it is an image of the original request (which works) using BurpSuite:
[image: Working request]

Then made this request in python:

```py
payload_img = make_payload_img()    # Creates an image and returns the name of it
post_url = f"{target}/upload.php"   # Target is the ip of who we are sending the request to
files = {
    'image': (payload_img, open(payload_img, 'rb'), "image/png"),
}
headers = {"Cache-Control": "max-age=0", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "Origin": "http://10.10.10.185", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", "Referer": "http://10.10.10.185/upload.php"}
# The proxies are just to intercept the request on BurpSuite
proxies = {
    "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
}

upload_file = s.post(post_url,files=files,headers=headers,proxies=proxies)
```

However in the intercepted request on BurpSuite is missing `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"` at the end:

[image: Not working]

Is it possible to add it manually or python requests multipart doesn't allow you to do so?

Comment: Does the code of python work?

Comment: @JIZHIHAOSAMA Yes, the last image from burpsuite is the request generated by the python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add it in `python-requests`.This is not the request header of it.
`form-data` represents the enctype way.Except `form-data`, there also have `form-urlencoded`, `text/plain`(less common).Get [more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) on wiki.

`Content-Disposition` : Because you used `files=file`. it would send by `form-data` normally.

`name="image"` : The name in the form.(In your circumstance, they are image).

`name="submit"` : This usually means the submit button of the form.When you click the button on the page,it would take this.(Mostly you don't need to add it).

If you really like to post it on the first way:

```
files = {
    'image': (payload_img, open(payload_img, 'rb'), "image/png"),
}
data = {
    "submit": "Upload Image".
}

requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=headers .... )
...
```

Comment: The point is that the manual way works and ends up uploading the file (first burpsuite image), and the second one doesn't. Used BurpSuite Comparer and those lines at the end were the only difference

Comment: @itasahobby So just pass `data` parameter in the post function.